# How to create or return seperate scope from function in ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures, angularjs-ng-repeat

Base Code:

```
  <tr class="" ng-repeat="row in resultOfFiltering">
       <td class="{{result[1]}}" ng-repeat="result in   createTableBody(row)">{{ result[0] }}</td>
  </tr>
```

source of resultOfFiltering is changed when watch notice changes in search input or there was choosen a new  base source, according to that new table body should be created

createTableBody is executed to search after nested fields and create proper order and amount of td in tr.

ISSUE: I think i know what the issue is, the issue is that all result keep reference to the last execution of createTableBody function, so the question would be how to create sepereate scope for each function execution ?

createTableBody function

```
this.createTableBody = function(obj){

       var headers = $rS._headers,
        giveBack;

    if(obj.headers !== headers.length) {

        var num = obj.headers;

        if(!angular.isArray(headers[num])){
          giveBack = obj[headers[num]];
        }else{
          giveBack = that.giveBackNestedValues(obj, headers[num]);
          obj.headers += 1;
          return giveBack;
        }
        obj.headers += 1;
        return [giveBack, headers[num] ];
    } else {
        return [undefined,'HideThisRow'];
    }

 };
```

I tried to wrapp return in function(){return something}) in order to create uniq scope but it doesn;t repair my issue.